# Core Data fetch using a predicate

Tags: swift, core-data

I have two core data entities, one is called Person and the other is Codes. A Person has a one-to-many relationship with Codes.

[image]
[image]

I want to retrieve all the Codes for a particular Person and have the following function:

```
static func fetchCodes(person: Person) -> [Codes]? {
    let context = getContext()
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Codes> = Codes.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Codes.number), ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    //print("person in fetchCodes=\(person.first)")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "whosAccount == %@", person)
    do {
        let codes: [Codes] = try context.fetch(Codes.fetchRequest())
        //print("Codes count from fetchCodes: \(codes.count)")
        return codes
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I have checked that the argument `person` is in fact the correct Person that I want to retrieve codes for but the result returns all Codes for all Persons. What am I missing?

Comment: What you are missing is a typo: `context.fetch(Codes.fetchRequest())` should be `context.fetch(fetchRequest)`.

Comment: @pbasdf:Thank you. That was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need a fetch or a predicate, you access the relation as an attribute

```
let codes = person.codes
```

Comment: Thank you. That is a much neater solution. This returns a Set which looks like this:`First code is: Optional(<Codes: 0x600002136440> (entity: Codes; id: 0x61480dce0533d92b <x-coredata://A2B634E4-E136-48E1-B2C5-82B6B68FBE44/Codes/p225> ; data: {
    code = RY6;
    number = 1;
    whosAccount = "0x61480dce3c73d90b <x-coredata://A2B634E4-E136-48E1-B2C5-82B6B68FBE44/Person/p4>";
}))`. How do I just extract the code and the number element? Also, I will need to sort the Set based on the number element.

Comment: I think you should read the [documentation for Set](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set) but you can iterate over a set to access all the Codes objects. Set is unordered but there are `sorted` methods you can call that returns a sorted array.

Comment: I am fairly new to Xcode/swift and have read the Set documentation but don't understand how to filter the set returned by `person.codes` to retrieve the `code = RY6` if I filter on `number = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the `Person` you don't need to fetch any data, just get the `codes` from the relationship

```
static func fetchCodes(person: Person) -> [Codes] {
    return person.codes
}
```